# Datagridview Cell Format Thousand Separator

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, formatting

I want to format VB.NET `datagridview` cell to show thousand separator with 2 decimal places like this
123,456,789.12
what i have tried already

```
DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"
DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#,###.##"
```

nothing worked it's keep showing 123456789.12

Note : I'm filling `datagridview` from database and I need to change cell format dynamically

Comment: The second one should be `"#,###.00"`, but either one will only work on a column with numbers.  Text data wouldnt be formatted and you should probably assign that to the numeric column so it doesnt try to format dates to that

Answer (score 0):

If your column type is of number type(such as double), the formating would do the work no matter in edit mode or not.
If your column type is of string type which is by default, you shoud handle the cellFormating event to do a trick work like below in c#:

```
  private void DgvCellStyle_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("a");

        dt.Rows.Add(155.6565);

        dt.Rows.Add(2342.2);

        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;



        this.dataGridView1.CellFormatting += new DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellFormatting);

    }



    void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)

    {

        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex != this.dataGridView1.NewRowIndex)

        {

            double d = double.Parse(e.Value.ToString());

            e.Value = d.ToString("N2");

        }

    }
```

this works for me as I retrieve the data as it is from the database and it seems that the datagridview see it as nvarchar (string)

You can check this  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/95e7e7ef-2e71-412f-abe5-ffbee2c12c18/how-to-format-datagridview-columns-to-numeric-columndefaultcellstyleformat-does-not-work?forum=winformsdatacontrols